# Issue in migration prestashop 1.7 from web server to local server

Tags: php, localhost, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

[Here is my website displayed when the website is on the web server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nykMl.png)

[Here is my website displayed when the website is on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDJHu.png)

Why is this difference, and How can I rectify it?
I migrated my prestashop v1.7 online shop from the web server to the localhost for development purpose and it doesn't look the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Theme css file is missing or may be it is present but not rendering. Clear cache and try.

Comment: I've tried everything.. 
1) Regenerating the .htacess file
2) Clearing cache
3) Recompiling templates
4) Even I inspected the page using chrome (Ctrl+Shift+I) and there were no errors shown

Nothing seems to work out :(
When I copied all the file from the server some 9 files wasn't successful, but now when I compare the files I see all the css files in the themes folder you told.